# Best method to monitor connectivity

Tags: connection, monitoring, ping

Asides from a constant 24/7 ping, how can I monitor a connection status to a site to ensure that it is up.

For example, 192.168.0.1 <-> 192.168.20.1, measuring the connection between these two sites.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to simulate the usual actions you perform when you are working with the site. For example if the other site is mostly used as a file server I would write a script that will copy files to and from the site. If it is a web server then loading the main page every few minutes is a good idea.For authentication servers logging in is what you want.

Try to think about the most common functionality and simulate it.